# Problem spawning grunt off an item pick up in amnesia

Tags: amnesia-the-dark-descent

I am relatively new to scripting for amnesia, I've watched a few videos as well as looked it up on wiki.frictionalgames.com but I have yet to find an answer.  I have script set up to spawn an enemy when I interact with an item, yet he spawns when I first start off in the map.  It's not an issue with the script I know this because I've checked at least 3 different sources and they all match up with mine, what else could be causing this issue?  Any information would be of great help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a monster to be spawned by a script, it must be **deactivated** in the level editor.  Open the level editor, and if the grunt is greyed out, then it is already deactivated.  Otherwise, click the monster and uncheck the "Active" checkbox.